# Spring Boot WebFlux tests failing after upgrade to Spring Boot 2.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, spring-webflux

I have some Spring Boot integration tests which worked fine in Spring Boot 2.1 but now that I have upgraded to Spring Boot 2.2 they're failing. Using default spring-boot parent dependency management. Some failing tests which used to work are as simple as this example:

```
...
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
 webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
 properties = {"spring.sleuth.enabled=false"})
@Import({AccountApiClient.class,...})
@DirtiesContext
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.CLASSPATH,
 ids = {"my.org.com:account-service:+:stubs:9021"},
 consumerName = "AccountServiceV2",
 stubsPerConsumer = true)
public class AccountsClientTest {

@Autowired
AccountService accountService;

@Test
public void verifyAccountsShouldReturnEmpty() {
    Mono<List<Accounts>> acc = accountService.getAccounts(new AccountId(ACC_ID));
    assertThat(acc.block(), hasSize(0));
 }
 ...
```

Before the upgrade, this test passes as expected but after the upgrade, it fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] verifyAccountsShouldReturnEmpty  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR!
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.lang.AssertionError: Spring Context [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7d605944, started on Tue Aug 18 10:00:09 CEST 2020, parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@a035db9] is not yet refreshed. This is unexpected. Reactor Context is [Context0{}] and name is [blocking]
```

I have many tests with similar behaviour after upgrading. It fails on line `assertThat(acc.block(), hasSize(0));`

What might be causing this?

### Update

I've tried changing the test to use StepVerifier as suggested in comments but didn't work:

```
@Test
public void verifyAccountsShouldReturnEmpty() {
  StepVerifier.create(
      accountService.getAccounts(new AccountId(ACC_ID)))
      .expectNext(Collections.emptyList())
      .verifyComplete();
}
```

The end of the error just changed to: `parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@985b9f6] is not yet refreshed. This is unexpected. Reactor Context is [Context0{}] and name is [stepVerifier ]))` which seems the same issue as using block but now with StepVerifier.

Comment: its is quite simple, you are blocking a reactive application, and blocking is not allowed. If you wish to test reactive return types use the `StepVerifier` and not `assert` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_testing_a_scenario_with_stepverifier

Comment: @ThomasAndolf - Unfortunately doesn't seem that simple.  I tried with StepVerifier and the result is the same only the error message end changes to ` [Context0{}] and the name is [stepVerifier ]` instead of the current one posted in the question.

Comment: Dont explain your code, post what you have tried because it is the solution and you are probably implementing it wrong.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf - sure mate. I have updated the question with the StepVerifier implementation and the error which seems still same issue.

Comment: i read up a bit on the exception and it has somerthing to do when you are not registering beans correctly in the spring context. i dont like the usage of `@DirtiesContext` can you please produce a small reproducible example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the support, I will try to do that. Also, I noticed that if I run those same tests directly from IntelliJ they actually pass, but not when running from the command line, or in the pipeline, so I am more puzzled by it now.

Comment: Then check your java versions could be that

Comment: Yep, sure. First thing I did. They're exactly the same. What I noticed is that if I run the tests in isolation they always pass, but when running all tests(even from IntelliJ) the reactive ones fail with this error.

Comment: Then you have what is called overbleeding between tests and in pretty sure the `@DirtiesContext` has something to do with it. If you declare it, it will destroy the entire context between tests. You should avoid using it because it slows down tests. Instead try with the aproach, clean up, set up test data, assert for each test using a combination of `@Before` and such to avoid test overbleeding.

Comment: Many think that `@DirtiesContext` is a simple way to just "reset" your application, but its not, destroying and rebuilding the context takes time. Only reason to use it is if you are doing something that makes the context irreparable for instance changing the state of something etc.

Comment: but it is hard to give any more advice without seeing your full source code.

Comment: Hi, I finally manage to sort it out. I will publish an answer for what solved in my case. relevant to notice that this project uses a combination of Spring MVC and WebFlux so it's running in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to sort it out, unfortunately not sure of the root cause but what fixed it was removing the properties from the @SpringBootTest annotation and using it's defaults. Clearly something has changed in there with the upgrade of the dependencies which caused the issue.

So it works when like this:

```
...
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

// below annotation properties were removed which fixed the tests...
@SpringBootTest

@Import({AccountApiClient.class,...})
@DirtiesContext
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.CLASSPATH,
 ids = {"my.org.com:account-service:+:stubs:9021"},
 consumerName = "AccountServiceV2",
 stubsPerConsumer = true)
public class AccountsClientTest {
```

Comment: Hmm, there is something i dont like, in your orginal post this `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext` is mentioned. This clearly says `servlet` which should not ne part of a reactive application...

Comment: As far as I know they're working hard to make Spring Web MVC and Spring WebFlux (reactive and non-reactive) co-exist in applications as this is definitely a requirement for many, many projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue after adding

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I solved this by removing @DirtiesContext

Comment: Hi, good to know. I tried removing the @DirtiesContext annotation and it didn't solve it in my case.